# Return True if alphanumeric (No methods or import allowed)

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop, boolean

What would be a good way to make a function return True if, and only if, what is inputted is alphanumeric (contains only letters or numbers), without using methods or import?

So far in class, we only covered `bools`, `while` loops, and `if`-statements, and are only allowed to use what we have learned.

This is what I got

```
def alphanumeric(s):
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == 1 or s[i] == 2 or s[i] == 3.....:
            i = i + 1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Is there a more concise way to do this without using methods or import?
What I have doesn't work, and returns False no matter what I input.

Resolved. Thank you to all that helped!

Comment: I am only allowed to use bools, while-loops, and if-statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `==` and `or` work. You need to test each and every character separately:

```
if s[i] == 1 or s[i] == 2 or s[i] == 3 ...:
```

or use an `in` test:

```
if s[i] in (1, 2, 3, 4, ...):
```

except that you are testing *characters* here, not integers, so either turn your character into an integer, or test against digits:

```
if int(s[i]) in (1, 2, 3, 4, ...):
```

or

```
if s[i] in '1234567890':
```

The latter works because strings are sequences too; testing if one character is in the string `'1234567890'` is a valid membership test too.

Since strings are sequences, you can also just loop over them directly:

```
for char in s:
    if char in '1234567890':
```

No need to use a `while` loop and counter there.

This still only tests for digits; to test for letters as well, you could do one of two things:

- Use the `string` module, it has `ascii_letters` and `digits` attributes:

  ```
  import string

  for char in s:
      if char in string.ascii_letters + string.digits:
  ```
- or test if the character is between two known characters:

  ```
  if 'a' <= char <= 'z' or 'A' <= char <= 'Z' or '0' <= char <= '9':
  ```

  and this works because strings are comparable and sortable; they are smaller or larger according to their position in the ASCII code table.

Your next problem is that you are returning `True` too early; you do this for the first match, but you need to test *all* characters. Only return `True` if you didn't find any misses:

```
for char in s:
    if char not in string.ascii_letters + string.digits:
        return False

return True
```

Now we test all characters, return `False` for the first character that is not alphanumeric, but only when the loop has completed, do we return `True`.

Comment: The expressions need to compare strings. s[i]=='1' etc.

Comment: The question says "we only covered bools, while loops, and if-statements, and are only allowed to use what we have learned". So I think there _is_ a need to use a `while` loop and counter instead of a `for` loop. (There also may be a need for a teacher who understands that `for` loops are easier to understand for novices, even if `while` loops are easier for C experts migrating to Python…)

Comment: @abarnert: I don't feel to restricted by that list; it may be incomplete, and I do aim to teach a little in these kinds of answers.

Comment: Ah! One problem I've encountered. If those special characters (*, #, ~, -, etc.) are embedded somewhere in the middle of the string, this function doesn't catch those for some reason.

Comment: @muros: The are not; see the [list of printable ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). `'a'` through to `'z'` (upper and lowercase) and `'0'` through to `'9'` are homogenous sequences.

Comment: What I meant was I get True even if my string has non-alphanumerical values. Only if the very first character in the string is not a letter or number, it comes out as False.

Comment: @muros: that is because you return `True` for the first match. You need to return *`False`* for the first miss instead, and only return `True` when you haven't found any misses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Python comparison operators to test against characters, so you could do something like this:

```
def is_alphanumeric(s):
  for ch in s:
    if not ('a' <= ch <= 'z' or 'A' <= ch <= 'Z' or '0' <= ch <= '9'):
      return False
  return True
```

That will loop through each character in the string and see if it is between 'a' and 'z' or 'A' and 'Z' or '0' and '9'.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *"no methods allowed"* means no *regex* or anything like that, you may use this.

I'll leave it to you to write out `string.digits` and `ascii_letters` manually if you have to ;) (That was a joke, you can actually use @mipadi 's method if you aren't allowed to `import string`)

```
from string import digits, ascii_letters as alphabet
valid = digits + alphabet
def alphanumeric(s):
    return all(c in valid for c in s)


>>> alphanumeric('1a')
True
>>> alphanumeric('_')
False
```

Equivalent to:

```
def alphanumeric(s):
    for c in s:
        if c not in valid:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: There are far more letters than ASCII letters!

Comment: @abarnert *ikegami* was alluding to the fact that OP should do that

Comment: @jamylak: The OP should do what? Type in thousands of lines worth of Unicode class data? I suppose that would be a good way to convince his teacher he's a smartass, but otherwise, why?

Comment: Why did you decide to arbitrary exclude one letter and not another. You didn't document your capricious decision.  My name is one of the most commonly given name to boys in the US, yet you decided that one spelling of it doesn't consist of letters without a mention of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `in` operator and iterate across the input string `s`:

```
for c in s:
    if c not in 'abcdefABC123':
```

Start with a flag being `True` and set it to `False` if any character violates the alphanumeric requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suppose that s is a String.

So you must do `s[i] == '1'` since `s[i]` is a substring and not an integer.

That is the reason your function always return False.
Then you return true or false only after looking at the first char, you must test every char until one isn't alphanumeric or until the end.

```
def alphanumeric(s):
    i = 0
    flag = True
    char = 'a...zA...Z0..9'
    charLen = len(char)
    while (i < len(s) and flag) :
        subflag = False
        charIndex = 0
        while charIndex < charLen:
            subflag = subflag or (s[i] == char[charIndex])
            charIndex += 1 # Equivalent of charIndex = charIndex + 1
        flag = flag and subflag
        i = i +1
    return flag
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

First, you're attempting to return True when you see an alphanumeric character - you need to check **all** of the characters before returning True (though you can return False when you see a single non-alphanumeric character).

Second, if s is a string, s[i] is a character (i.e. '1', not 1).

Third, when you wrote

```
if s[i] == 1 or 2 or 3
```

you're evaluating (s[i] == 1), then 2 by itself as a boolean (which is always false), etc. To compare s[i] to each, you need

```
if s[i] == '1' or s[i] == '2' or s[i] == '3'
```

or, more concisely,

```
if s[i] in ['1', '2', '3', ...]
```

Comment: BBrown is correct - you can also use

    if s[i] in '123456...'

Answer (score 0):

```
def isAlphaNumeric(myString):
    return not any((c for c in myString if not c in "abcdef...ABC...123"))
```